# web api self host custom ioc inject data to controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, self-hosting

I have a property in my web api self hosted app that I would like to inject to my controllers, which is loaded via reflection using my custom IoC framework, here is my startup code:

```
public CustomClass StuffInstance { get; set; }


// This method is required by Katana:
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ConfigureOAuth(app);
    var webApiConfiguration = ConfigureWebApi();

    // Use the extension method provided by the WebApi.Owin library:
    app.UseWebApi(webApiConfiguration);
}
```

my controllers are mostly scaffolded and some like:

```
// PUT: api/EventTypeDescriptions/5
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
public IHttpActionResult PutStuff(int id, int something)
{
    //do stuff
    //here i would like to use StuffInstance like a singleton
    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

how can a inject StuffInstance to my controllers? this information would be relevant to anyone making an IoC framework btw

Comment: What are you using for your IoC?  You need to assign the IoC resolver to the config, and create an interface that represents CustomClass.

Comment: its a custom thing, but im considering using autofac maybe, with my custom resolver could i inject the instance somehow?

Comment: It doesn't matter so much what you use; you just need to use something.  You have to register you controllers and resolve the dependencies for them when they are requested and you aren't doing anything like that here.

Comment: i upvoted your comment for suggesting i use an interface but i still dont know how to inject an instance to my controller, any info on that? maybe a link to the info i need to read?

Comment: I've added an AutoFac example for you.  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

I found the information to inject instances to my controllers in this link:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection

basically i implemented a dependency resolver for my custom IoC Library

in case someone has the same problem, here is the code, maybe for other IoC frameworks it needs more work

```
public class CustomIocDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly CustomIoc container;

    public ComponentLoaderWebApiDependencyResolver(CustomIoc container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    IDependencyScope IDependencyResolver.BeginScope()
    {
        return new CustomIocDependencyResolver(container);
    }

    Object IDependencyScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return container.GetInstance(serviceType);
    }

    IEnumerable<Object> IDependencyScope.GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return container.GetAllInstances(serviceType);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

now my katana Configuration looks like:

```
    // This method is required by Katana:
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureOAuth(app);
        var config = ConfigureWebApi();

        config.DependencyResolver = CustomIocDependencyResolver(container);

        // Use the extension method provided by the WebApi.Owin library:
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
```

being container the instance of my custom IoC

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned AutoFac as a potential candidate, I recommend you follow their [tutorial](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#owin-integration) on WebAPI integration.  You'll need to define an interface on CustomClass so that you can properly inject it.

You'll need to inject your instance that you've created (since you want to treat it as a singleton) by registering it as an instance component.

```
public interface ICustomClass {}
public class CustomClass : ICustomClass {}

public CustomClass _stuffInstance = new CustomClass();

public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureOAuth(app);

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        builder.RegisterInstance(_stuffInstance).As<ICustomClass>();

        var container = builder.Build();
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
        app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

Then, in each controller's constructor, inject your instance that's been bound to the appropriate interface.

```
public class CustomController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ICustomClass _customClass;

    public CustomController(ICustomClass customClass)
    {
        _customClass = customClass;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With ASP.NET Core 6 you can now register a service provider:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICustomClass, CustomClass>(sp => new CustomClass()/* or your already existing instance */);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICustomClass>(sp => new CustomClass()/* or your already existing singleton instance */);
```

it will be injected to your controllers:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ICustomClass _customClass;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public MyController(ICustomClass customClass, ILogger<MyController> logger)
    {
        _customClass = customClass;
        _logger = logger;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this will be useful when I upgrade!